# Looping through multi-dimensional array in javascript skips data?

Tags: javascript

I have the following array:

```
let array = [1, 2, 3, [(4, 5, [(6, 7, 8)], 9, [10])]];
```

I'm using recursion to loop through and reduce it down to a single array.

To start, I just want to `console.log(array)` within the `for` loop. So code is:

```
function reduceArray(array) {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    console.log(array[i])
  }
}
```

Expecting to see 4 elements of:

```
1
2
3
[(4, 5, [(6, 7, 8)], 9, [10])]
```

I instead get:

```
1
2
3
[10]
```

What's happening here?

Comment: Your array initializer is not correct; the `( )` are superfluous. They're being interpreted as expressions with comma operators.

Comment: superfluous implies they have no significance, but that's not correct.

Comment: @junvar yes I was verifying that it was doing what I thought it was :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have parens `()`, which you seem to assume do nothing, but they actually do have meaning in JS and most languages. Here, the `()`'s mean the `,` is interpreted as **comma operators** instead of as delimiters for arrays.

- `3` evaluates to `3`, simple enough.
- `[3, 4]` interprets the `,` as an array delimiter and evaluates to an array with 2 elements.
- `(x(), 3, 5)` interprets the `,` as the comma operator and evaluates to `5`, but also invokes `x()`, which may have side affects.
- `[3, (x(), 6)]` interprets the 1st `,` as an array delimiter, interprets the 2nd `,` as the comma operator, and evaluates to `[3, 6]`, but also invokes `x()`.

Here's another example:

```js
let y = 10;
let incY = () => y++;
console.log((incY(), incY(), y));
```

So returning to your example, when you have `[(4, 5, [(6, 7, 8)], 9, [10])]`, that evaluates to `[10]`.

> The comma operator (,) simply evaluates both of its operands and returns the value of the last operand. [MDN, comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Comma_operator)

Comment: I had a feeling that had something to do with it, but I have a code simplifier (for lack of a better term) plugin on my editor (VS) and it automatically sets those parentheses. Probably time to switch to a different one.